# Как задать изображение в поста в шаблоне поста

Tags: wordpress, acf

Хочу сделать так чтобы на странице поста выводилась миниатюра поста на всю ширину экрана. Пример вот здесь [тема Tini Hestia](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/tiny-hestia/) (после перехода нажмите на кнопку "Просмотреть" в колонке справа). Розовая часть поста сверху и есть пример который хочу у себя в теме создать. 
Насколько я понял там не выводится изображение а divу задан бэкраунд с изображением.
Может кто нибудь подксказать как это организовано?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, просто добавить стили (в теме возможно так и сделано, не смотрел):

```
body {
    background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```